# Registrar protocolo "https" com certificado para requisição SOAP(Axis 2)

Tags: java, multithreading, certificado-digital, https, concorrência

Eu criei um serviço para registrar o protocolo "https" e injetar o certificado nele usando a implementação de SocketFactory, porém funciona bem apenas uma solicitação de cada vez, mas ao usar multi-threading não dá certo, é como se pegasse o certificado errado na hora da requisição no webservice. As classes SOAP do webservice foram geradas pelo Axis 2 usando o WSDL salvo da página.

**Código para registrar protocolo e injetar certificado (PFX):**

```
public boolean assinar(InputStream pfx, final String password) throws Exception {
    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(getBytesFromInputStream(pfx));
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(in, password.toCharArray());
        in.close();
        Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
        String alias = null;

        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
            if (ks.isKeyEntry(alias)) break;
        }

        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
        SocketFactoryDynamic socketFactoryDinamico = new SocketFactoryDynamic(certificate, privateKey);
        socketFactoryDinamico.setFileCacerts("NFeCacerts");
        Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", socketFactoryDinamico, 443));
        return true;
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Eu quero consultar vários clientes ao mesmo tempo no webservice, mas os certificados são diferentes. Caso queiram saber, os webservices são de NF-e do Brasil.

Comment: Vou supor que você isolou as conexões. Dito isto, você precisa agora isola os certificados e os dados de acesso de acordo com as conexões. Uma maneira de fazer isto é usando ThreadLocal.